# Move a SQL Server Agent job from dev server to test server using a SQL script

Tags: sql-server, database, database-administration, sql-server-agent

I created a SQL Server job on the dev server with name `Job_Test`. Now my team wants me to create a new job on dev with name `Job_Dev` and move `Job_Test` to the test server.

Is there a way to just transfer `Job_Test` to the test server without having to create a new job on the test server using SQL script?

Comment: Right click the job in SSMS, click Script as CREATE to query window, switch the window's connection to the other server and run the script

Comment: Learn to do EVERYTHING via tsql. Then you never have problems moving things or modifying things. And now you need to add this to your disaster recovery plan. You DO have one of those, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can generate script from your job in any server then run it on test server.As following

[image]
[Here](http://www.sqlcircuit.com/2013/08/how-to-script-all-sql-agent-jobs-in.html)